# Triggering another always block from an always block

Tags: verilog, hdl

In the below image,there's the code for parity generation.
State represented by even_odd and output as z. What will happen if the circled red part as in the image has blocking assignments instead of nonblocking? Will verilog start executing the 2nd always block (the one triggered by change in even_odd) without finishing the execution of 1st always block?

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. The example posted is not good to illustrate it though, as the "blocking" assignments in it won't actually block anything and probably won't change the behavior.

Comment: If I assume there are other statements in the always block, then what will happen?

Comment: I would really help to post the code as text, not a picture of it.

Answer (score 1):

It would make a difference if you changed the first `always` to blocking assignments to `even_odd` and used the value of `z` on code that followed the `case` statement.

Verilog does not guarantee the order of execution between statements executing in parallel processes. This allows for optimizations that allow `even_odd` and `z` become the same signal, effectively eliminating the second `always` process. So you would have a race condition using blocking assignments.

You would also have a race condition if `even_odd` went to any other `always @(posedge clk)` process and tried to read it.